# IMC 2008 first problem first day. Finding continuous functions so $x-y\in \mathbb Q \implies f(x)-f(y)\in \mathbb Q$

Tags: calculus, continuity, contest-math, rational-numbers

I would like an alternate solution and proof verification for the following problem:

Find all continuous functions $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ so that if $x-y$ is rational then $f(x)-f(y)$ is rational.

My solution:

Given $r\in \mathbb Q$ let $g(x)=f(x+r)-f(x)$. $g(x)$ is continuous since $f(x)$ and $f(x+r)$ are continuous, the latter because $f(x+r)$ is the composition of the continuous functions $f$ and $x+r$, the claim follows from the fact the subtraction of two continuous functions is continuous.

Suppose $g(x)\neq g(y)$ Pick $z$ irrational between $g(x)$ and $g(y)$ exclusive, by the intermediate value there is a $c$ so that $g(c)=z$, that is $f(c)-f(c-r)$ is irrational while $c+r-c=r$ is rational, a contradiction, therefore $g(x)$ is constant.

We prove if $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are given then the function $f$ is uniquely determined, proof: given a rational number $a$ take $k$ and $l$ positive integers so that $ka=l$.

On the one hand $f(l)=f(0)+l(f(1)-f(0))$, the proof is simple by induction, f(1)=f(0)+f(1)-f(0) clearly. $f(n+1)-f(n)=f(1)-f(0)$ since $f(x+1)-f(x)$ is constant and so from here:

$f(n+1)=f(n)+f(1)-f(0)=f(0)+n(f(1)-f(0))+f(1)-f(0)=$ $f(0)+n+1(f(1)-f(0))$ by induction hypothesis.

Analogously $f(ka)=f(0)+k(f(a)-f(0))$ and since $l=ka$ we obtain $f(0)+k(f(a)-f(0))=f(0)+l(f(1)-f(0))$ from here $f(a)-f(0)=(f(1)-f(0))\frac{l}{k}$.
Therefore the function is uniquely determined for all rational numbers. And hence also for all real numbers, this is because if $f$ and $h$ are continuous with $f(x)=h(x)$ for all rational $x$ then $h=f$, otherwise there would be an $x_0$ with $f(x_0)-g(x_0)\neq 0$, by continuity there is $\delta>0$ so that $f(x)-g(x)\neq 0$ for $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, this is impossible because there is a rational number in that interval.

So given $a=f(0)$ and $b=f(1)-f(0)$ the function is uniquely determined, of course $f(1)-f(0)$ must be rational. Notice that $f(x)=bx+a$ works, and hence these are the only functions that work. Just to be clear, the functions we want are $bx+a$ with $b\in \mathbb Q,a\in\mathbb R$

Than you very much in advance, regards.

Comment: Putting each paragraph in its own hint box is a bit inconvenient.

Comment: it doesn't work if you make a hint box very big.

Comment: Haven't read the rest yet, but initial thoughts is that your first paragraph is very verbose. I don't think it's necessary to explain so much: it is evident enough to most readers that if $f(x)$ is continuous than so is $f(x+r)$ and that the difference of two continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: ok, thanks, I am going to compete in the IMC so I don't know if I can just say that $g(x)$ is clearly continuous, I think so, but I don't want to lose points.

Comment: @dREaM Simply saying $f(x+r)$ is clearly continuous, hence $g(x)$ is continuous, shouldn't lose you any points. Especially if you say "by theorem"

Comment: Edit in second line of the first answer $f(x+r)$ (add the parenthesis)

Comment: I have removed the hint boxes: since the paragraph is preceded by "My solution" it is unlikely someone that is interested in not reading the solution will proceed to read it. On the other hand, it is very bothersome for someone who does want to read it to have to hover over each box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is correct.
I would do it only slightly differently, and more briefly:

First, for any $r\in\mathbb Q$ the function $x\mapsto f(x+r)-f(x)$ only takes rational values and is continuous, so it must be constant; call it $c_r$.
A simple iteration gives $f(x+kr)-f(x)=kc_r$ for any $k\in\mathbb Z$.
For the different constants $c_r$ to be compatible with this relation, we must in fact have $c_{kr}=kc_r$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$.
But now also $c_{kr/q}=kc_{r/q}=k\frac1qc_{qr/q}=\frac kq c_r$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$ and $q\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$.
We have thus found that $f(x+p)-f(x)=pc_1$ for all $p\in\mathbb Q$.
Putting $x=0$ gives $f(p)=f(0)+pc_1$ for all rationals $p$.
The rationals are dense and $f$ is continuous, so $f(p)=f(0)+pc_1$ for any $p\in\mathbb R$.
The number $f(0)$ is real and $c_1$ is rational numbers; on the other hand any function of this form does clearly satisfy the condition.

Comment: @dREaM, thanks. I made the correction.